# Jquery php scroll issues. how to detect images inside div?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a shout box coded in php and javascript using ajax and I have a problem with the shoutbox scrolling when images load inside the shoutbox.
Each new shout is added to the bottom and it scrolls down.

Problem: When an image is posted the shoutbox does not scroll to the bottom of the image.
Reason: Image is posted scroll has already been triggered then the image will load fully load increasing its size to the max size set in css.
meaning that you will then have to manually scroll to the bottom to see the full image.

I am currently using the

```
$(window).load(function() {
tbSingleScroll();
```

});

The problem with this is... only works when changing pages and I have to wait for all images to finish loading on the whole page.

Which is kind of alot compared to the tiny amount of images / smileys that may be in the shoutbox.

I have been trying to solve this problem myself for longer than I can remember.
Any help with this would be amazing..

Answer (score 0):

You looking for http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/03/lazy-image-loading-jquery-javascript.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Attach load event to all your shoutbox images and add a count to calculate how much has been loaded and only then change the dimensions or scroll down.

For example:

```
var shoutbox_img_count = $('#shoutbox').find('img').size();
var shoutbox_loaded_count = 0;

$('#my_shoutbox').find('img').load(function() {
   shoutbox_loaded_count++;
   if (shoutbox_loaded_count == shoutbox_img_count) {
      // Do a scroll here
   }
});
```

**Or**
use static image/icon size so that when a new node is created it would automatically appear as a container even if image is still loading

Comment: This is kind of not what I am looking for as any image could be posted from anywhere, so adding a load to each image some one posted would involve a preg match.

Is there anyway to detect images in a certain div IE the div all the  
shouts are loaded in is #shouts.. If I could detect an image just in there it would do the trick.

Comment: Why a preg match? You can easily insert a new hidden container, bind live load events in the beginning of a script to all the images(by accessing them like $(container).find('img'); ) and after that you can show the container

Comment: I gonna be honest with you.. I am new to Jquery I mean I spent 3 days so far learning it.. I don't know much about javascript and I want to learn.

I think in little time I have actually learnt alot.
I understand that if I added onload= to all the images in the shoutbox then the code above will work.

I understand your answer I just don't understand how I could do this without adding onload to the actual images.
I am thinking that if I add
$("img").addClass("shoutbox");

Comment: Learning is the best thing to do! :) Maybe you show us your live preview with code and so people could help you out much more as I myself don't know if I imagine your problem correctly.

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't let me edit my last comment and I pressed enter by mistake.. I will finish that off here


I am thinking that if I add
$("img").addClass("my_shoutbox");
I could probably use
$('img.my_shoutbox').find('img').load(function()(

I am presuming that would work?

Comment: Simply $('img.my_shoutbox') is enough as you are adding "my_shoutbox" class to IMG element so there's no need to do ".find('img')" as "$('img.my_shoutbox')" is already pointing to IMG with class="my_shoutbox" :)

Comment: my website is www.uniquez-home.com
A live preview can be seen there

you do need an account to view the shoutbox..

Comment: Its hard to explain lol.
Errm to sum me up I am a perfectionist I have to have things working properly.
If there is room for improvement you can guarantee I am on it.

Basically. I have a SB and inside the div #shouts
is where all the shouts are posted.
I want to beable to detect all images inside the sb and when they have loaded call the scroll function.

Now its a shoutbox so the images can come from anywhere..
So I just want only that div to be detected of images not the whole website

Then the scrolling will be more efficient as it trigger alot faster than waiting for a whole page to load